# 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.' after adding chromedriver to my PATH

Tags: python, selenium, terminal, selenium-chromedriver

I have spent hours trying to get this working to no avail. I am trying to run this test script:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com")
headlines = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("story-heading")
for headline in headlines:
    print(headline.text.strip())
```

I have installed selenium and downloaded chromedriver as well as adding it to my PATH using `sudo nano /etc/paths` and adding entering the path /Users/Myname/Desktop/chromedriver. I closed out the terminal and checked it using echo $PATH and that path showed in my PATH so I'm sure it's there and /Users/Myname/Desktop/chromedriver is the location of my chromedriver exe file. However when I run the .py script above it returns "'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH." and I don't know what else to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the actual path to the `*.exe` or `chromedriver.exe` in the function call, there is no need to add it to your PC's PATH variable.

**NOTE: Just to clarify, for example**

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Myname/Desktop/chromedriver.exe") # In Actual Add The Path To chromedriver.exe or whatever *.exe in here
```

Only you can know where you exe is located so just add the exe path in the function rest it will be done for you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Success! Thank you so much for clarifying this for me!!!